# How to chain error.response.json() in a promise without nesting it in the catch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bluebird

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the server error response promise

```
error.response.json();
```

without nesting it in the catch(). Is there a way this can be done outside of the catch and still only be called when there is an error?

```
return doGet(`/rest/hello-world`)
      .then(json => json.ListResponse)
      .then(result => {
        return dispatch({
          type: LOAD_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(error =>
        error.response.json().then(result => {
          return dispatch({
            type: LOAD_FAIL,
            error: result.error.message,
          });
        })
      );
```

Comment: No. Why would you think there should be a way?

Comment: Are you using `fetch()` to make request?

Comment: @Bergi I'm getting "Avoid nesting promises" warnings from eslint, so I wasn't sure if what I am doing was best practice for error handling.

Comment: No nested `Promise` patterns appear at JavaScript at Question. What is the issue with nesting `Promise` calls or functions which return a `Promise`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes

Comment: @Bergi _"No"_ That is not true for `fetch()`

Comment: @guest271314 I believe the eslint validation doesn't like that I have a `.then` method wrapped in a `.then` method. Perhaps if there is nothing wrong with the doing it this way, it's something I should look into tweaking with my eslint rules.

Comment: @KidsAndTheHall There's indeed nothing wrong with this. Sometimes this is just what you need, not all nested `then` calls can be flattened.

Comment: @Bergi okay thank you, I will leave it for now.

Comment: Can you include text of `doGet` function at Question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way this can be done outside of the catch and still only be called when there is an error?

No.

> I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the server error response

It works [quite a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572), but I suspect what you actually wanted to write is

```
return doGet(`/rest/hello-world`)
      .then(json => ({
              type: LOAD_SUCCESS,
              data: json.ListResponse.data,
            }),
            error =>
              error.response.json().then(result => ({
                type: LOAD_FAIL,
                error: result.error.message,
              }))
      )
      .then(dispatch);
```

You might also want to consider the case that `error.response.json()` rejects on malformed responses.

Comment: What is expected result of `error.response.json()`? Is that a bluebird specific syntax?

Comment: @guest271314 no, this has nothing to do with Bluebird. It's just the syntax that the OP used in his question; I don't know what `doGet` does exactly.

Comment: _"I don't know what doGet does exactly."_ Where does `json` come from if not from a `Response.json()` call, as OP mentioned using `fetch()`? `Response` can only be read once, then `bodyUsed` flag is set to `true`. You could not then call `.json()` again within second parameter to `.then()` if the original `Response` object has been read and the `Response` object is not cloned and used for that call.

Comment: @guest271314 You'll have to ask someone who knows what `doGet` does. But it doesn't look like it would call `.json()` twice on the response.

Comment: Your code calls `.json()` twice, else `json` at first `.then()` comes from where?

Comment: @guest271314 It comes from `doGet`, and I won't repeat that I don't know what it does internally. My code does use `error` in the same way as the code in the question, it's possible that there is a problem with the design of `doGet` but that's not what was asked about.

Comment: `doGet` is just a custom function that calls `fetch()` and returns the response

Comment: Really do not care if you repeat yourself or not. Your code repeats itself where it is not possible to do so, that is self-evident.

Comment: @KidsAndTheHall The same  `body` from `Response` cannot be read twice

Comment: @KidsAndTheHall you probably should put the `error.response.json()` call inside the `doGet` logic as well. That'll also reduce the nesting on the outside :-) Make sure to also generate appropriate errors (with a message?) when there is no response and `fetch` itself rejects. If you post your full code, possible as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), we can help you on that as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response.clone()` to clone the `Response` and perform other tasks with the `Response` object

```
fetch("/url")
.then(response => {
  // do stuff with cloned `Response`
  const clone = response.clone();
  clone.json().catch(err => console.log(err));
  return response.json()
})
.then(json => /* do stuff */)
```

Comment: [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) has no `catch` method. What is this code supposed to do, and what does it have to do with the question? Why do you think the response needs to be cloned?

Comment: @Bergi `.json()` should have been chained to `clone` before `.catch()`, updated. The code clones the `Response` and handles network error separately from original `Response`

Comment: But why? a) you still use nested promise handlers and b) cloning makes absolutely no sense here, you could just as well have used `const x = response.json(); x.catch(…); return x;`

Comment: @Bergi Well, your evaluation of what makes sense is your own. OP appears to want to handle `Response` separately from original `Promise` chain.